# A connection was established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, connection, connection-string

I am currently trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database table and query some values, but I am not able to do so as I am always getting the following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was closed by the remote host)

or in german:

> Es konnte eine Verbindung mit dem Server hergestellt werden, doch während des Handshakes vor der Anmeldung trat ein Fehler auf. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen.)

As the sql exception suggests, I was actually able to connect to the postgreSQL database, but then I am getting this error, any idea what is going wrong here?

The exception is thrown when I execute the connection.Open() method.

I have already tried to solve this problem on my own by searching through the forum but no success. I altered my connectionstring (added a timeout of 30 seconds and an application name), and restarted VS and rebuilded the projected.

My connection string is looking like this currently:

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.UserID = Username;
        builder.Password = Password;
        builder.InitialCatalog = Database;
        builder.DataSource = Hostname + "," + Port;
        builder.ApplicationName = "EdgeidComparison";
        builder.ConnectTimeout = 30;

        Connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong here?
Thank you so much in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: SqlConnectionStringBuilder is for SQL Server. PostgreSQL doesn’t use that. You probably want NpgsqlConnectionBuilder

Comment: ohh I did not know that! thank you, I will try it out and give you feedback :)

Comment: you are my hero thank you!! I did not realize there was a nuget package for that.